# Set Array Equal to Another Array without Specified Key/Values

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to mirror the behavior of `newArray = oldArray`, with the caveat of excluding some key/values of the `oldArray`, so something like `newArray = oldArray - undesiredOldKeyValue`. I realize this is fully doable with a `foreach` on the `oldArray` and using an `if` to see if the encountered key is desired or not, but I am interested in a simpler or more concise approach if possible.

A couple of things to keep in mind, I need to exclude key/value pairs based on key, not value. I do not want to modify the `oldArray` in the process of doing this.

Comment: See [`array_filter()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use [array_filer](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php). Something like:

```
$new_array = array_filter($old_array, function ($value, $key) {
    // return false if you don't want a value, true if you want it.
    // Example 1: `return $value != 'do not keep this one';`
    // Example 2: `return !in_array($key, ['unwanted-key1', 'unwanted-key2', 'etc']);`
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

It will filters elements of an array using a callback function.

Comment: `return ! in_array($key, ['undesired-key1', 'undesired-key2', 'etc']);`

Comment: The call to [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) needs a third argument in order to also pass the keys to the callback.

Comment: @axiac thanks, I added two examples!

Comment: @axiac haha thanks again!!